# Query Too Complex, despite it only containing 5 linked queries and one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've looked into this issue and have not found a solution for my issue. I've analyzied the SQL code and cannot find any issues (I'm not good at SQL) and have spent about 2 hours trying to solve the issue but I cannot figure it out.

The table is used for a video game, it is a database for keeping track of shooting range scores in Ravenfield. I'll go ahead and post the SQL for someone to anaylize.

The table is set up by joining multiple queries together, however, they're not complex queries, and the data is fairly simple. The main table is the weapon information table, and the rest are the range tables.

Here is the sql for those who want to look at it to tell me if something is wrong with my SQL:

```sql
SELECT [Weapon Information].[Weapon Name], [Weapon Information].[Weapon ID], [Weapon Information].[Sub ID], [Weapon Information].[Based On], [Weapon Information].[Country of Origin], [Weapon Information].Type, [Weapon Information].Caliber, [Weapon Information].Capacity, [Weapon Information].Manufacture, [Pistol-1 Final]![Final Score]+[Rifle-1 Final]![Final Score]+[Indoor Range Final]![Final Score]+[Testing Field Final]![Final Score]+[CQB-2 Final]![Final Score] AS [Final Score], [Pistol-1 Final]![Final hits]+[Rifle-1 Final]![Final hits]+[Indoor Range Final]![Final hits]+[Testing Field Final]![Final hits]+[CQB-2 Final]![Final hits] AS [Final Hits], [Pistol-1 Final]![Final Misses]+[Rifle-1 Final]![Final Misses]+[Indoor Range Final]![Final Misses]+[Testing Field Final]![Final Misses]+[CQB-2 Final]![Final Misses] AS [Final Misses], [Final Hits]/[Final Misses] AS [Final Accuracy]
FROM (((([Weapon Information] INNER JOIN [Pistol-1 Final] ON ([Weapon Information].[Sub ID] = [Pistol-1 Final].[Sub ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon ID] = [Pistol-1 Final].[Weapon ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon Name] = [Pistol-1 Final].[Weapon Name])) INNER JOIN [Rifle-1 Final] ON ([Weapon Information].[Sub ID] = [Rifle-1 Final].[Sub ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon ID] = [Rifle-1 Final].[Weapon ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon Name] = [Rifle-1 Final].[Weapon Name])) INNER JOIN [Indoor Range Final] ON ([Weapon Information].[Sub ID] = [Indoor Range Final].[Sub ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon ID] = [Indoor Range Final].[Weapon ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon Name] = [Indoor Range Final].[Weapon Name])) INNER JOIN [Testing Field Final] ON ([Weapon Information].[Sub ID] = [Testing Field Final].[Sub ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon ID] = [Testing Field Final].[Weapon ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon Name] = [Testing Field Final].[Weapon Name])) INNER JOIN [CQB-2 Final] ON ([Weapon Information].[Sub ID] = [CQB-2 Final].[Sub ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon ID] = [CQB-2 Final].[Weapon ID]) AND ([Weapon Information].[Weapon Name] = [CQB-2 Final].[Weapon Name]);
```

Comment: Nearly impossible to analyze without data. Error is clear. Simplify query. Question is not really appropriate for SO. Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: It is confusing what is tables and what is queries. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Don't know ms access, but does it allow to re-use a calculation in the same select? If not, then this would fail :  `[Final Hits]/[Final Misses] AS [Final Accuracy]`

Comment: Yes, a calculation can be used in same SELECT.

Comment: Alright I decided to spend the rest of my day simplifying it and that didn't work. I cleaned up relationships, anaylize my SQL, and still nothing. Finally, at approximately 5 PM I threw in the towel and turned the 5 main queries into action queries that created tables and made the final query refer to the tables instead which now works like a charm. No error messages. It is a bit annoying that i have to run the action querries but it is better than nothing I guess. I'll play with the table for a while and see if the issue is resolved but it seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

You've got NULL data somewhere. The query analyzer hits the NULL data, can't complete the query plan, and crashes out. Fix it by wrapping with ISNULL where required -- or restructure using a table so that the query analyzer doesn't try to move up the selection criteria to a place where it's not valid. (Also, replace all those ! with . )